# how to save and retrieve cookies using ajax webservice calls

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, cookies, web-services

Hi I have web app which stores certain things on a page in a cookie when the page posts back in case the user doesn't finish what they're doing and come back later.  But now I must do a javascript time-out and actively save the info to the cookie rather than wait for the user to postback.  All my cookie code is on server side where I use Response and Request objects to read and write cookies and I want to leverage that.  So I would like to just use ajax calls to a webservice.  Is there a way for me to access Request and Response objects and read and write cookies to the browser via those objects during a webservice call?  Or should I just go with javascript?

EDIT: Sorry i wanted to specify that I would like to use jquery-ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I created the static web method on .cs side of the page and in the method I enable session.  So this way, I can save stuff to cookie by making ajax calls and using my already existing .cs cookie code.

Answer (score 0):

Implement an ajax callback on a timer that posts back every *n* number of seconds.  When the ajax posts back, check your constraints and simply update the cookie.

Comment: yes my question is how to exactly do that using ajax? EDIT: jquery-ajax specifically.  Should I just create a webmethod on the .cs side of the page?